# Can I find out if an Android iOS or Windows Phone 8 push notification was delivered?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Can you interrogate the Apple (APNS), Google (GCM) or Windows Phone push notification servers after the fact to find if a notification was delivered?

I know that when a server initially sends the push notification there is a response to say whether the message was processed (but this doesn't mean delivered) or rejected by the notification server. But is there any way to subsequently find out via Android, iOS or Windows Phone 8 if the message was delivered?

Ideally I'd like to achieve this just by interrogating the vendor's push notification server, worst case I'm assuming I'd have to put something in my app to register that a given notification arrived and somehow transmit this success status back to my server.

Comment: No for Apple. It's a one way street.

Answer (score 0):

APNS, GCM and MPNs don't offer this functionality.

You'll have to support it yourself, by sending an acknowledgment from the app to your server whenever a notification reaches your app.

For GCM you can view statistics of deliveries, but nothing for individual deliveries :

> Viewing Statistics
>
> To view statistics and any error messages for your GCM applications:
>
> ```
> Go to the Developer Console.
> Login with your developer account.
>
> You will see a page that has a list of all of your apps.
> Click on the "statistics" link next to the app for which you want to view GCM
> ```
>
> stats.
>
> ```
> Now you are on the statistics page.
> Go to the drop-down menu and select the GCM metric you want to view.
> ```
>
> Note: Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM. You
>   must use the Developer Console.

Comment: Got. it. Does the Android GCM Developer Console only show the stats for the entire app (all notifications ever sent) or can you filter by a specific notification ID?

Comment: @rihallix I don't know, since I've never seen this console, but I don't think you'll get details for specific registration IDs.

Comment: So assuming there is no interaction, if the notification arrives at the device can it trigger any functionality within my app to record the arrival?

My assumption was that the notification's arrival was independent of the app. So only if the notification is clicked on can my app get involved (I'm hoping these two statements are incorrect).

Comment: @rihallix On Android you can execute application code regardless of whether it's clicked or not. On iOS and Windows Phone it has to be clicked before your app gets the notification data, though I believe in iOS7 you can execute some background work before the user clicks the notification.

Comment: I do see that APNS has a feedback mechanism where you can later interrogate APNS and get a list of ids and dates that apps were uninstalled. APNS appear to recommend polling daily to obtain these values. Nothing that conclusively identifies delivery though.

Comment: @rihallix The Feedback service only tells you about (most of the) devices that uninstalled your app, but it doesn't tell you anything about delivery to devices where your app is still installed (and it won't tell you even about some of the devices that uninstalled the app, because in some cases APNS doesn't know that a device uninstalled the app - for example, if the device is offline).